# How to create a slideToggle which closes the one open

Tags: jquery

I have the following example:

http://jsfiddle.net/zidski/Vn9RD/

When link one is opened and then I click on link two, how do i close link one?

```
$('a.county').each( function(e){
    $(this).bind('click', function(e){ 
        var thisIs = $(this).index(); 
        $('.countystats').eq(thisIs).slideToggle(100); });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just slide the other ones up first:

```
$('.countystats').slideUp();
$('.countystats').eq(thisIs).slideDown(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this tricky way,
Your html will like...

```
<div id="1sub" class="sub">sub1</div>
<div id="2sub" class="sub">sub2</div>
<div id="3sub" class="sub">sub3</div>

<div id="stream-1" class="stream" style="display:none;">Stream 1</div>
<div id="stream-2" class="stream" style="display:none;">Stream 2</div>
<div id="stream-3" class="stream" style="display:none;">Stream 3</div>
```

Now,in jquery

```
$(".sub").click(function(){
var subClicked = $(this).attr('id');
$(".stream").hide();
$("#stream-" + subClicked.substring(0,1)).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can capture the current element you want to manipulate - and use [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to filter it out

```
$('a.county').bind('click', function (e) {
    var thisIs = $(this).index();
    var $el = $('.countystats').eq(thisIs); // element you want to toggle
    $el.slideToggle(100);
    $('.countystats').not($el).slideUp(100); // slide all the other ones up
});
```

<kbd>[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DSF6w/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.county').on('click',function(){
    $('.countystats').slideUp(300);
    $('.countystats').eq($(this).index()).slideDown(300);
});
```

I have updated your fiddle, check that one also. http://jsfiddle.net/Vn9RD/3/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("a.county").on("click", function(e) {     
    var target = $(this).data("div");   
    $(target).slideToggle("fast");
    $(".countystats").not(target).hide();
    e.preventDefault();   
});
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/7TdSK/

i hope it helps.